# golang - extract elements in xml string

Tags: xml, go

I want to extract all `loc` element value but I am getting an empty array

My code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

type Query struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"urlset"`
    locs []Loc `xml:"url>loc"`
}

type Loc struct {
    loc string 
}

var data = []byte(`<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
   <loc>http://www.konga.com/mobile-recharge</loc>
   <lastmod>2015-04-14</lastmod>
   <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
   <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
   <loc>http://www.konga.com/beauty-health-personal-care</loc>
   <lastmod>2015-04-14</lastmod>
   <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
   <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
</urlset>`)


func main() {

    var q Query
    xml.Unmarshal(data, &q)
    fmt.Println(q.locs)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only unmarshals exported and thus Caps fields. Also `Loc` shouldn't be a struct but can be a string directly.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/xml"
    "fmt"
)

type Query struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"urlset"`
    Locs    []Loc    `xml:"url>loc"`
}

type Loc string

var data = []byte(`<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
<url>
   <loc>http://www.konga.com/mobile-recharge</loc>
   <lastmod>2015-04-14</lastmod>
   <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
   <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
   <loc>http://www.konga.com/beauty-health-personal-care</loc>
   <lastmod>2015-04-14</lastmod>
   <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
   <priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
</urlset>`)

func main() {

    var q Query
    xml.Unmarshal(data, &q)
    fmt.Println(q.Locs)
}
```